# Is there a way to exclude resource groups that Azure creates for Azure Backup from policy assignment?

Tags: azure, azure-policy, azure-backup-vault

I wanted to know is there any way to exclude resource group that Azure creates for Azure Backup from the policy assignment. I have created a deny policy assignment and that policy restricts the creation of the Azure Backup resource group since the deny policy requires tags while provisioning. Kindly let me know if there is any way to tackle this.

Comment: I don't think you're in the correct place. StackOverflow is for programming questions only. This sounds more like a question for https://ServerFault.com

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude managed resources from a policy, then you can add logic like this to their definition’s policy rule:

```
{
    "value": "[resourcegroup().managedBy]",
    "notContains": "Microsoft.<managed by rp namespace> "
}
```